# SQL Server 2005 SQLAgent Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, triggers, database-connection, remote-connection

I need to set up a SQL Server trigger to connect to a remote mysql linux server and insert data into a table. Is there a way to do this?

I'm leaning towards triggers rather than scheduled tasks because the trigger will execute each time data is entered/updated in the SQL Server table and only 1 record will be passed to the MySQL table at a time, cutting down on large data transfers and creating a more 'realtime' transfer appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a trigger for this.

Create a linked server to the remote server, create a stored procedure to insert the data into the linked server and then schedule a task under SQL Agent to run the stored procedure.

- [Writing a Stored Procedure](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513004137/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111499-1.shtml)
- [How to: Schedule a Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Comment: Can you provide some tutorial or link explaining how to create a stored procedure please? Thanks! Also, will this work when connecting to a Linux MySQL server?

Comment: Also, why is using a scheduled task better than a trigger? A scheduled task will dump to mysql tables multiple records at a time while triggers will be executed for 1 record at a time keeping data transfer to a minimum and populating the mysql table in seemingly realtime...which seems more ideal